# Get Values from Nested Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an Array and another Nested Array of Objects, I want to filter the record in Nested Array of Objects that has all the elements of Array. In example below I want to keep the array with Id :2 as it has both Javascript and Salesforce as Name in Contacts.
Array = [Javascript,Salesforce]
Array of Object = `

```
[
     {
      "Id":"1",
      "Country":"USA",
      "Contact":[
         {
            "Name":"Javascript",
            "City":"ABC",
         },
      ],
   },
{
      "Id":"2",
      "Country":"USA",
      "Contact":[
         {
            "Name":"Javascript",
            "City":"ABC",
         },
         {
            "Name":"Salesforce",
            "City":"XYZ",
         },
      ],
   },
]
```

`

I am trying Javascript to filter out the values `

```
[{
          "Id":"2",
          "Country":"USA",
          "Contact":[
             {
                "Name":"Javascript",
                "City":"ABC",
             },
             {
                "Name":"Salesforce",
                "City":"XYZ",
             },
          ],
       },
]
```

`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can use JavaScript's `Array.prototype.filter` method. What have you tried? I recommend writing out the logic for what you want to happen in some sort of pseudo-code to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find an item which has both `Javascript` and `Salesforce` as contacts, you can use `filter` and `some`

```
data.filter(item =>
  item.Contact.some(contact => contact.Name === 'Javascript') &&
  item.Contact.some(contact => contact.Name === 'Salesforce')
)
```

```js
const data = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Contact": [{
      "Name": "Javascript",
      "City": "ABC",
    }, ],
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Contact": [{
        "Name": "Javascript",
        "City": "ABC",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Salesforce",
        "City": "XYZ",
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result = data.filter(item =>
  item.Contact.some(contact => contact.Name === 'Javascript') &&
  item.Contact.some(contact => contact.Name === 'Salesforce')
)

console.log(result)
```

Or `filter` and `map`

```
const result = data.filter(item => {
  const names = item.Contact.map(contact => contact.Name)
  return names.includes('Javascript') && names.includes('Salesforce')
})
```

```js
const data = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Contact": [{
      "Name": "Javascript",
      "City": "ABC",
    }, ],
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Contact": [{
        "Name": "Javascript",
        "City": "ABC",
      },
      {
        "Name": "Salesforce",
        "City": "XYZ",
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result = data.filter(item => {
  const names = item.Contact.map(contact => contact.Name)
  return names.includes('Javascript') && names.includes('Salesforce')
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Konard, How can we cover the same  if the Array List is dynamic and can have multiple elements from 1 to 5 ?

Comment: @RuchiSharma should work for multiple elements as well